# crontab -e run as root and not as user

Tags: linux, crontab

When I am login as a user (lets say: John) to may linux (Ubuntu 18), I run the command:

```
crontab -e
```

I then entered a simple command:

```
python pythonFile.py
```

I was expecting the job to run under user "John" but insted, when running:

```
ps -ef|grep pythonFile
```

I see the job running under root. I can't understand why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `crontab -e -u <username>` (as root) - I couldn't tell you why it's doing that though - unless it's specific to Ubuntu, or python wants to run as root (?)

Comment: @Smock Thanks, But it open the same crontabthat I get with crontab -e and the python script is there but still in the process list it run with root privilege and not the user John

Comment: try `crontab -l -u <username>` (as root) - see if it is definitely in the user crontab and just running as root for some reason. If you run it manually, does it run as your user or root?

Comment: @Smock,  Strange, I checked and its in the user cron tab. Still it seems it is running under root BUT I think that the commands in the python are executed as the User. This is really strange but since I don't know exactly how to explain this, I think I will  leave it for now until I will have more data on the problem. Thank for your reply.